# WebGL: Text rendering and blend issue

Tags: text, textures, webgl, blend

Hy

I have a rendering issue with text in WebGL.
Here the pb:

[image: BUG example]

The first rendering is crappy the second is OK.
The difference is my DOM (nothing related to the HTML DOM):

[image: DOM representation]

The difference between the view V2 and V3 is:

- V2 is just a green rectangle (composed of 2 GL triangles) and contains a DOM child V4 which is a Text View (means a text, render into a Canvas then copy into a texture)
  The blend is done by the GPU
- V3 is TextView with a green background. The text is rendered into a Canvas then into a texture (like the V4). And a Shader fill the rectangle and takes the texture to generate the final view => no blend (actually done by the shader)

It should be a problem of blend and texture configuration. But I cannot find the right configuration.

Here my default configuration for the blend:

```js
gl_ctx.disable (gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
gl_ctx.enable (gl_ctx.BLEND);
gl_ctx.blendFunc (gl_ctx.SRC_ALPHA, gl_ctx.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl_ctx.clearDepth (1.0);
gl_ctx.clearColor (1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

NOTE 1: A view (Vn) is the basic document object into my WebGL toolkit. It's called internally a Sprite, it's composed basically by 4 vertices, and a vertex and fragment shaders are associated to it, for the rendering purpose.

NOTE 2: If I use this blend configuration:

```js
gl_ctx.blendFunc (gl_ctx.ONE, gl_ctx.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The text rendering works well but the rest of rendering, specially images had incorrect alpha.

NOTE 3: sorry dont have enough reputation(!!!) to include image in my post :-(

Answer (score 0):

Canvas 2D always uses pre-multiplied alpha so you pretty much have to use the second blendfunc. Can you set that blendfunc just when you render text?

Comment: Ok thx for the tip :-)

Yes I can change the blend functions during my rendering.
I will investigate that.

But will be simpler if I could be able to generate right texture.